Extending ApplicationUser on a fresh Blazor Server-only project with Individual accounts
I'm trying to extend ApplicationUser with custom properties on a fresh Blazor server project. Here's what I have:
public class Tariff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public double MonthlyFee { get; set; }
    public int NetworkSpeed { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Added field and foreignkey attribute after, but that changed nothing
    public int TariffId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TariffId))]

    public required Tariff Tariff { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>(options)
{
    public DbSet<Tariff> Tariff { get; set; }
}


After applying generated migration, I got a Tariff table with corresponding columns and a TariffId column in AspNetUsers table.
I've also modified registration process to be as following:
var user = Activator.CreateInstance<ApplicationUser>();
var defaultTariff = DbContext.Tariff.FirstOrDefault();
user.Tariff = defaultTariff!;
return user;

And manually populated Tariff table with example rows. After that, I'm trying to access the field in a Blazor page.
@page "/Account/Personal"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using WebApp.Components.Account.Shared
@using WebApp.Data

@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject IdentityUserAccessor UserAccessor
@inject IdentityRedirectManager RedirectManager
@inject ApplicationDbContext DbContext

<InputSelect id="tariff" @bind-Value=user.Tariff>
    @foreach (var tariff in DbContext.Tariff.ToList())
    {
        <option value="@tariff">@tariff.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    private ApplicationUser user = default!;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = await UserAccessor.GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext);
    }
}

But debugger shows that Tariff field is null. However other fields - i.e. TariffId and Balance are populated normally.
What am I missing for auto-filling this property?
Edit1: I've also tried to set public required Tariff Tariff { get; set; } as virtual but this didn't work. Also tried to change Id to TariffId in Tariff - same thing

DbContext.Tariff.FirstOrDefault() is returning null in my assumption.

@DA after registration the TariffId is populated correctly with id=1 in database with this code, and when accessing user in Blazor page, user instance has TariffId = 1, but Tariff = null. And just iterating over DbContext.Tariff is also working properly - I can play with InputSelect without bind-value no-problem.
